# Stereo sound design to surround mix

Tags: mixing, 5.1, reaper, pro-tools, surround-sound

Hi,
I'm an independent sound designer and I've worked on several projects with other sound mixers already but all these projects had stereo soundtracks.
I'm kind of a newbie when it come to surround mix. I can't do surround so I'd have to give my sound design to a mixer who would have the right equipment.

Let's imagine that the mixer works on pro tools and I work on Reaper. How does that work ? What do I give him in order for him to do a proper surround mix ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to export stems for him. Or a whole bunch of consolidated audio files of each track.

I use REAPER as well and if I was doing something like this I'd look at doing stems. Something along the lines of:
- Dialogue
- Atmos
- Foley
- SFX (possibly multiple stems here depending on the complexity of your design)
- Music

I'd ask him what he would like and if you can sit in during the mix. If you're able to take in your REAPER project on a laptop during the mix you'll be able to export any individual elements that you need from a stem to mix separately.